# Sudden Violent Audio Volume Jump and Static Noise - Intermittent, but SCARY AF

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have an intermittent but almost heart attack inducing issue whereby Ubuntu/PulseAudio/Alsa appears to suddenly cause an issue that causes an otherwise low volume audio output (Amp is not set to a loud volume) to suddenly spew out a crackling/hissing/static like noise, but almost as though the amp has been turned to top volume...

Today this was experienced using Kodi. Yesterday was experienced through Youtube in Chrome...

Strangely, I've not heard this in several months, but has now occurred twice in as many days...

I'm as follows:
Ubuntu 20.10 (Also experience on 20.04)
Kernel 5.9.10 (also experienced in pre 5 from what I remember)
pulseaudio 13.99.2

Audio has been, but also experienced the same issues as:
Audio over HDMI
Audio over DisplayLink
Audio directly to amp over 3.5mm

Interestingly, I also seem to have an issue that pauses audio for approx 100ms regularly...

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 1):

This is something I’ve seen with some setups over the years when system notification sounds interfere with whatever is being played at the moment. The volume will GO RIGHT UP TO 11 FOR A SECOND, then return to normal. To call it annoying would be an understatement, particularly when it happens at 1:30am.

Fortunately there is a fix:

1. Open a terminal
2. Type `sudo vi /etc/pulse/daemon.conf` (feel free to use any editor, so long as you’re editing with `sudo`
3. Set `flat-volumes = no`
4. Restart PulseAudio with `pulseaudio -k`

That should do the trick. Hope it saves you from a heart attack

Comment: Thanks Matigo... In my case I have to jump across the room and switch the amp off, unpluig hdmi to retrieve audio back to the laptop, then jiggerypoker the whole affair back together... 

Going to give this a go... "flat-volume = no" was commented out...

Will give it a go and let you know...